# Middleware in flask

Tags: python, cookies, flask, middleware

I just stated using Flask and was trying to implement a small feature in my project. The objective is to set a cookie only if the request comes from a authenticated user.

I found two ways of doing this.

First method

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
   # set cookie if user is logged in
```

Second method, by implementing something like this 
[adding-a-simple-middleware-to-your-flask-application](https://ohadp.com/adding-a-simple-middleware-to-your-flask-application-in-1-minutes-89782de379a1#.xq8zafufd)

Can someone explain to me what are the main differences between the two methods and when and where which method should be used.

Also, I am currently using "flask-login" to keep track of the logged in user.
If I use the first method, I can easily verify if someone is logged in by importing the current_user

```
from flask.ext.login import current_user
```

but if I try to do the same while using the second method, the current_user is always "None" as the application context is incorrect.

So, I wanted to know if I decided to go ahead with the second implementation, how do I check if the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never used the second method you've mentioned. I'm sure that it can be done with it, but it's very uncommon. I would suggest to use more common features of flask. For sake of maintainers of your code :)
So the first method you've mentioned is fine.

Or you can use [decorators](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/viewdecorators/) for more granular access restrictions. Keep in mind that [setting cookies in flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#cookies) can be done when making actual response object. That means you should use [Deferred Request Callbacks](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/deferredcallbacks/) for setting cookies in decorated function.

Comment: Second option has its use cases because it covers the cycle of before and after request, which is usually split intto 2 functions. Some middleware need to have access to both. werkzeug middleware is implemented in this way, i.e. https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/middleware/dispatcher/. Its basically a wsgi app middleware, not strictly flask middleware.